# Atopiclair does not appear on any FDA list I can find

Tags: usa, openfda, drugs

Atopiclair is on drugs.com:

https://www.drugs.com/cdi/atopiclair.html

Here's where it's not (on fda.gov):

- The FDA CDER DB:
  https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cder/daf/index.cfm
- The Medical Device DB:
  https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/scripts/cdrh/cfdocs/cfRL/rl.cfm
- The National Drug Code Directory:
  https://www.fda.gov/Drugs/InformationOnDrugs/ucm142438.htm

Is the drug listed anywhere on fda.gov?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This document from fda.gov (saved via the Wayback Machine) states](http://web.archive.org/web/20161221003028/https://www.fda.gov/cdrh/510k/K024367.pdf):

> This clinical study was compiled using Sinclair Wound and Skin Emulsion product as submitted in 510(k) # K024367. Atopiclair" is the working name for Sinclair Wound and Skin Emulsion in this study.

[Searching fda.gov for the working name provides some results](https://search.usa.gov/search?query=Sinclair+Wound+and+Skin+Emulsion&affiliate=fda1)

I could be wrong about using the working name, if so, please let me know.